# Is a build relying only on fire damage viable?

Tags: dungeons-of-dredmor

I'm currently running a build relying almost only on fire damage (through the Promethean Magic skill) for defeating enemies. Currently when I encounter fire-resistant monsters I either whack them with a stick or rely on the high damage on the fire wall spell (Gog's Tactical Pyre) to penetrate their resistance. At the moment I'm on level 8.

I wanted to know if this is a viable build even for late game, or will I encounter too many powerful fire-resistant monsters and I need to think of some alternative (for instance, I have Alchemy, so maybe I should start stockpiling flasks of acid or noxious brimstone).

Comment: This is pretty much my build at the moment, although I've also got assassination as a skill tree, which gives me occasional Lethal Poison to play with.  I think it's going to depend on what some of your other skills are, but I bet you've got something in your bag of tricks that should help against fire resistant enemies...

Comment: Might help to know what the rest of your build is.  While I killed Dredmor in the old system with a fire build, it was strongly backed by mathemagic for high hitting damage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I've just finished the game relying almost exclusively on fire damage, and I think the answer is **barely**. Some late-game monsters have high fire resistance, so killing them with fire alone takes a long time and requires strong spells. At least those monsters usually also deal fire damage of their own, which Promethean mages resist.

Specifically, there's a late-game area of the game completely filled with fire-resistant monsters:

> Floor 9 is fire-oriented and almost all mobs there resist fire. There was a monster zoo there which took me *forever* to clear.

My recommendations:

1. Make sure you can efficiently use fireball and firewall by the late-game, in my experience they are the only ones that can penetrate high-resist enemies.
2. Make sure you have *some* alternative way of doing damage. I relied on a decent-damage staff and on acid flasks created through alchemy.